# Error when installing sql server using docker on macbook

Tags: docker

Error response from daemon:

> pull access denied for microsoft/mssql-server-linux, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

[image]

Comment: [why you shouldn't post images instead of texts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the reason is there is no Docker repository called `microsoft/mssql-server-linux`.

Use this command instead if you want [Microsoft SQL Server on Linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server):

```sh
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

Comment: It works but then when I try to use below command I get warning -> "The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested". And due to this warning I am unable to run sql server and use it further. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

The previous command pulls the latest SQL Server 2022 (16.x) Linux container image. If you want to pull a specific image, you add a colon and the tag name, such as mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-GA-ubuntu. To see all available images, see the https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server

The SA_PASSWORD environment variable is deprecated. Use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead.

sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong@Passw0rd" 
-p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 
-d 
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

SOURCE LINK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash